# Unity ingame GUI

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to create a GUI that could be at the bottom of a player's screen all the time. Not a main-menu UI, but an interactive, in-game UI.

For example:

[image: mw2 UI]

[image: mc UI]

It is crucial that the player in unity must be able to interact with the UI (*i.e.* click it) and it is also extremely crucial that the UI can be controlled by code (C#). I must be able to create and control this UI **programmatically**.

How would I go about this?

I have the very latest version of Unity3d installed.

Comment: You may find this link useful.
http://johnstejskal.com/wp/unity3d-how-to-make-a-2d-gui-hud-interface-to-display-scorelives

Comment: So you want to instantiate Unity UI components at run time? https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/user-interface-ui 
It sounds like you already know what you have to do?

Comment: From the official tutorial, https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/projects/survival-shooter/health-hud

Comment: what you are describing is absolutely trivial.  (1) click "add canvas" (handy tip - always choose 'scale with screen size'; Unity accidentally made the wrong default)  (2) click to add Button, Image, Slider or whatever you need.  the examples you give are utterly trivial. you can do them in less time than it takes to type this.  there is no "dynamic" involved at all.  obviously you can change the scores and so on with code like .text="27";  For something as "difficult" as making a map or button appear/disappear, just turn it on/off.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you can't learn that here.

**1**. Learn Basic UI. Go to the Unity website and lean each UI compoent such as Button, Image, Panels...

https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/user-interface-ui

**2**. Learn photoshop/Illustrator to get the good UI quality from the first link or hire a UI artist. Many videos on Youtube for photoshop/Illustrator UI design.

https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=photoshop+ui+design+tutorial

**3**. Learn C#. Important Unity API for this:

```
Unity events
IPointerClickHandler
IPointerDownHandler
IPointerEnterHandler
IPointerExitHandler
IPointerUpHandler
Button.onClick ((Button.onClick event)
Text
Image
Slider
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for a HQ answer. Also for not spoon feeding

Comment: @unity412 lol I don't know if that was sarcasm but you are welcome.